# How to sum variables in a column where a particular condition is satisfied in R?

Tags: r

```
    NoofPreg glu  bp skin  bmi   ped age yes/no
1          6 148  72   35 33.6 0.627  50    Yes
2          1  85  66   29 26.6 0.351  31     No
3          1  89  66   23 28.1 0.167  21     No
4          3  78  50   32 31.0 0.248  26    Yes
5          2 197  70   45 30.5 0.158  53    Yes
```

I am new to R, but I could not find any explanation online on how to do such operation on a dataset in R.
In the above dataset I want to sum glu variable where yes/no == "Yes". This is a conditional sum as to give me the sum of all the glu rows where yes/no is "Yes". How would you approach such problem in a R?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: ```with(df, sum(glu[`yes/no` == "Yes"]))```

Comment: Have a look at `?make.names`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
> with(dat, sum(glu[yes.no=="Yes"]))
[1] 423
```

where `dat` looks like this

```
> dat
  NoofPreg glu bp skin  bmi   ped age yes.no
1        6 148 72   35 33.6 0.627  50    Yes
2        1  85 66   29 26.6 0.351  31     No
3        1  89 66   23 28.1 0.167  21     No
4        3  78 50   32 31.0 0.248  26    Yes
5        2 197 70   45 30.5 0.158  53    Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is another variation you can surely try.............

```
sum(df[df$yes.no=="yes",]$glu)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: sum(df$glu[df$yes.no=="YES"])

df is your data.